# HTML Table Cell to display partial text with 'Show more/less' button to display/hide full content

Tags: html, css, html-table

**Issue:**
I have a HTML table which has multiple columns with the last column being "Stack Trace" which is usually very big. And displaying complete stack trace makes the Table formatting BAD.

**Objective:**
Want to display the "Stack Trace" as partial text with a 'Show more/less' button. When the 'Show more/less' is clicked for a particular cell, it should display/hide the complete "Stack Trace" for that particular cell.

Below is my csv file.

```
DATETIME,HOST,REQUEST,STACK_TRACE
5/13/2022 15:04:05,host1,POST,"java.lang.Exception: Stack trace at java.base/java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1383) at com.ericgoebelbecker.stacktraces.StackTrace.d(StackTrace.java:23) at com.ericgoebelbecker.stacktraces.StackTrace.c(StackTrace.java:19) at com.ericgoebelbecker.stacktraces.StackTrace.b(StackTrace.java:15) at com.ericgoebelbecker.stacktraces.StackTrace.a(StackTrace.java:11) at com.ericgoebelbecker.stacktraces.StackTrace.main(StackTrace.java:7)"
5/13/2022 15:06:05,host2,POST,"Exception in thread ""main"" java.lang.RuntimeException: A test exception   at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)   at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodA(StackTraceExample.java:9)   at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.main(StackTraceExample.java:5)"
5/13/2022 15:07:05,host5,GET,"java.lang.Throwable: A test exception   at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackElementExample.methodD(StackElementExample.java:23)   at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackElementExample.methodC(StackElementExample.java:15)   at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackElementExampleTest     .whenElementOneIsReadUsingThrowable_thenMethodCatchingThrowableIsObtained(StackElementExampleTest.java:34)"
```

**CSS Solution tried: -**

```
<head><style>
table{ 
    width:100%; 
    table-layout: fixed; 
    overflow-wrap: break-word; 
} 
th:nth-child(4){ width:60%; }
td:nth-child(4){
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
</style></head>
```

**Observations:**
It shows partial "Stack Trace" without any 'Show more/less' option.

[image]

**I want a 'Show more/less' button/link, which when clicked should display/hide the complete "Stack Trace" for that particular row cell.**

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this for a start so you have an idea. Let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showa").click(function() {
    $("td p.a").css("overflow", "visible");
     $("td p.a").css("white-space", "normal");
  });
  
    $(".hidea").click(function() {
    $("td p.a").css("overflow", "ellipsis");
     $("td p.a").css("white-space", "nowrap");
  });
  
  $(".showb").click(function() {
    $("td p.b").css("overflow", "visible");
     $("td p.b").css("white-space", "normal");
  });
  
    $(".hideb").click(function() {
    $("td p.b").css("overflow", "ellipsis");
     $("td p.b").css("white-space", "nowrap");
  });

});
```

```css
table{ 
    width:100%; 
    table-layout: fixed; 
    overflow-wrap: break-word; 
} 
th:nth-child(4){ width:60%; }
td:nth-child(4){
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  

}

td:active {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table colspan="4">
<tr>
 <th>Datetime</th>
 <th>Host</th>
 <th>Request</th>
 <th>Stack_Trace</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>123</td>
 <td>host1</td>
 <td>post</td>
 <td><p class="a">adadasfafsa aSFsfasgagadhsgadhsfjhsfjdgj blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah</p> </td>
 <td><button class="showa">Show</button><button class="hidea"> Hide </button></td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
 <td>123</td>
 <td>host1</td>
 <td>post</td>
 <td><p class="b">blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah adadasfafsa aSFsfasgagadhsgadhsfjhsfjdgj blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah blah blah  blah</p> </td>
 <td><button class="showb">Show</button><button class="hideb"> Hide </button></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You @Crystal for your solution. While this partially solves my problem, but not completely.
Why I wanted the 'show more/less' option was to be able to expand multiple columns and see full contents of all the columns simultaneously (for comparison) and if required, also copy the full contents from multiple columns.

Comment: This is the fast one I can think of. adding another td of button will do that. I'm not an extreme fan of table but I think this will work. Let me know.